# Import Video from Camcorder using Pixela ImageMixer Vs. Windows Import

Tags: windows-7, video, mts, m2ts

I have a Canon HF10. The camera came bundled with a Pixela ImageMixser SE, which is used to import the videos to your computer.

As this software is giving me grief, can I just use Windows Import Wizard?

The difference is that the latter generates .mts files, whilst the first generates .m2ts ones.

Comment: This down voting is infuriating. At least one should leave an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Windows 7 Import Wizard and compared the files. Mostly they were identical, except that in some situations Windows 7 Import Wizard split one file to a few smaller ones.